# Ubuntu 18.04 "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'" after "pip install boto3"?

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

This appears to be a new problem in Ubuntu 18.04... I don't have this problem in Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm unable to use `import boto3` in my Python scripts. This is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'
```

I'm getting the error AFTER successfully completing `pip install boto3`.

The machine is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04. I'm using the `/usr/bin/python3` that came with it.

This problem is fully reproducible on any fresh install, so I guess it must be common. What's the solution?

Comment: `pip3 install boto3`? The most obvious explanation is that you have multiple python versions so I'd try that first.

Comment: yep, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this happens when you have multiple python versions installed AND it's presumably the default setup on Ubuntu 18.04.

To fix:

```
pip3 install boto3
```

Note the **3** at the end of `pip3`.